# Moving the point between in charactors by quick search

Tags: vim

I'm looking for quicker ways to navigate in vim.

Say, I open the following text in a buffer:

> Vim is a highly configurable text editor built to enable efficient
>   text editing.  It is an improved version of the vi editor distributed
>   with most UNIX systems. Vim is distributed free as charityware.  If
>   you find Vim a useful addition to your life

Currently, my cursor is on line 1, character 1.

If I want to move the cursor to the start of the word `version`,
that would rather slow by using simple cursor movement (`hjkl` keys) to move to the specific line and character.

Now, I'm looking for the command that you could use, like `'` perhaps?. So you'd just need to type something like `'version`, and the cursor jumps to that word.

I hope this is possible (do I need a plugin for this?)

Comment: `$ vimtutor` is your best friend. The answer to your question is in the 4th chapter. You are supposed to go through it BEFORE you actually try to use Vim. Ho, I just re-read the title of your question and the answer is already in it. Are you joking?

Comment: Actually, i don't know this command `vimtutor` before your comment

Comment: right after vimtutor, `:set spell` would be appropriate :)

Comment: `vimtutor` is the basic Vim tutorial, you start the tutorial by typing `vimtutor` at the prompt in a terminal window. Logically, you know how to move around, jump, yank, paste, select visually after the first or second time. The whole tutorial can be finished in about 30 min and it's INVALUABLE if you are serious about learning Vim. It's definetely not enough to claim victory, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are **before** the point you want to go:

`/version` then `<Enter>`

If you are **after** you want to go:

`?version` then `<Enter>`

*For more info type:*

`:help search-commands`

Comment: The `/version` difference is that we need to press the <enter> key after searching, the `'version` is not. So, i think this will be faster.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>I took the time to write the question a bit clearer.</sub>

In addition to the search functionality already mentioned:

<kbd>/</kbd>`version`

I suggest to

```
:set incsearch
```

which enables incremental search while doing that (sweet)

```
:se hlsearch
```

for on the fly highlighting of (*incremental*) matches

#### Character searches:

1. Within lines, you can use <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to jump to the next `v` (<kbd>F</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to search backwards).
2. You can navigate sentences (using <kbd>)</kbd>, <kbd>(</kbd>)
3. paragraphs (using  <kbd>}</kbd>, <kbd>{</kbd>)
4. words (using  <kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd> as well as  <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd> and many others)

It's all you can eat, like a kid in the candy store! Here is the candy store:

### **[`:he motion.txt`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html)**